# Regex substitution on Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

The following Python script produces the unexpected output.

```
import re

s = """Test some texts here.
%\print{asdasd}
sdas dsad dad dasd.
\print{dddd}
sad sds asd s dasd a ddddsdas asdad.
"""
regex = r'^\\print\{.+?\}'
m = re.search(regex, s, re.MULTILINE)
print(m)
print("--------------")
ms = re.sub(regex, '9999999', s, re.MULTILINE)
print(ms)
```

which not substitutes `\print{dddd}` by `9999999` in `ms` variable.

Note that `m` is not `None` here, and it matches `\print{dddd}` correctly.

Can you please explain why it happens, and how can I solve this?

You can try the code here -> https://trinket.io/python3/f9663471c1

Comment: It is a common known problem. Use `flags=re.M` inside `re.sub`.

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor. You save my day.